# Add CSS when input is valid - CSS Challenge

Tags: html, css, frontend, netsuite

Context: I'm working within netsuite which adds spans around it's inputs, Therefore I can't use bootstraps floating labels since it targets the direct child input after the div in which it's called.

My Goal: The text inside of the floating label floats when the input is focused, but when I input something inside the field, it drops back down. I need the style to stay applied when I'm not currently clicked on the field.

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="custom_floating mb-3">
        <span>
            <input type="text" class="" id="firstname" placeholder=""> 
        </span>
        <label for="floatingFirstName" class="form-control-placeholder">
            First Name <span style="color: red;">*</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .custom_floating > span:focus-within + label {
  opacity: 0.65;
  transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0.15rem);
}
```

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: It seems there is no way to achieve this only by CSS. You need to use Javascript to add the new styles to the label.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label{
  color:red;
}
input:placeholder-shown + label{
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="custom_floating mb-3">
        <span>
            <input type="text" class="" id="firstname" placeholder="name"> 
       
        <label for="floatingFirstName" class="form-control-placeholder">
            First Name <span style="color: red;">*</span>
        </label>
           </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

> input should have placeholder

Comment: I added an input it's just in JavaScript because in netsuite that's how you have to do it. This works great, could you just move the label outside of the span? Thanks for helping!